# How do I properly implement merge sort

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

I have the merge sort code below which is not giving proper output.
Input :  1 7 3 9 4 5 2 6 8
Output : 1 5 2 6 7 3 8 1 9.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void merge(vector<int>& array,vector<int>& helper,int low,int mid,int high)
{
    int size = array.size();
    for(int i =0;i<size;i++)
        helper.push_back(array[i]);
    //helper = array; // copy vector elements i .. copying references doesnt work hence
    int current = low;
    int helperLeft = low;
    int helperRight = mid+1;
    while(helperLeft<=mid && helperRight <=high)
    {
        if(helper[helperLeft]<helper[helperRight])
        {   array[current] = helper[helperLeft];
            helperLeft++;
        }
        else
        {
            array[current] = helper[helperRight];
            helperRight++;
        }
        current++;
    }
    int remaining = mid - helperLeft;
    for (int i = 0; i <= remaining; i++) 
        array[current + i] = helper[helperLeft + i];
    // copy the remaining elements from the left only and not right because right elememts are already there in dest (array) sorted.
}

void mergeSort(vector<int>&array,vector<int>& helper,int low,int high)
{
    if(low < high)
    {
        int mid = (low+high)/2;
        mergeSort(array,helper,low,mid);// sort left half
        mergeSort(array,helper,mid+1,high);// sort right half
        merge(array,helper,low,mid,high);
    }
}

void mergeSort(vector<int>& array)
{
    vector<int> helper;
    mergeSort(array,helper,0,array.size());
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    int i =1;
    v.push_back(i);
    v.push_back(i+6);
    v.push_back(i+2);
    v.push_back(i+8);
    v.push_back(i+3);
    v.push_back(i+4);
    v.push_back(i+1);
    v.push_back(i+5);
    v.push_back(i+7);
    vector<int>::iterator it=v.begin();
    while(it!=v.end())
    {
        cout<<" "<<*it;
        it++;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    mergeSort(v);
    it = v.begin();
    while(it!=v.end())
    {
        cout<<" "<<*it;
        it++;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

I am using C++ vectors here instead of arrays as passing size will be a problem?
Can somebody please hep me correct the mistake here?

Comment: This code doesn't even run, `array[current + i] = helper[helperLeft + i];` goes out of bounds

Comment: Hi dwcanillas , please compile and test the output of this code .. it works   $ ./a.out
 1 7 3 9 4 5 2 6 8
                                  .............. 1 5 2 6 7 3 8 1 9

Comment: Sure, it gets to the point where it generates output in a release build, but it still goes out of bounds.  In a debug build, it doesn't even get that far.  You need to rethink your algorithm because it is wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately I think there is no out of bounds problem here as I had put debug logs to print array each time within merge function ... both helper and array have same sizes and the logic ensures that only appropriate number of elements are placed in the destination array .. there is some flaw somewhere else which I am not able to catch.. out of bounds doesnt look a problem to me..

Comment: Did you really? http://ideone.com/uBx7dS

Look at the last line: You are calling `array[9]` when there are only 9 elements in the array, which is going out of bounds.  Why do you ask for help if you are just going to refuse to believe what you are being told?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.The correct solution is posted below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void merge(vector<int> &array,int low,int mid,int high)
{
    vector<int> helper(array);
    //helper = array; // copy vector elements i .. copying references doesnt work hence
    int current = low;
    int helperLeft = low;
    int helperRight = mid+1;
    while(helperLeft<=mid && helperRight <=high)
    {
        if(helper[helperLeft]<helper[helperRight])
        {   
            array[current] = helper[helperLeft];
            helperLeft++;
        }
        else
        {
            array[current] = helper[helperRight];
            helperRight++;
        }
        current++;
    }
    while(helperLeft<=mid)    
        array[current++] = helper[helperLeft++];
    // copy the remaining elements from the left only and not right because right elememts are already there in dest (array) sorted.
}

void mergeSort(vector<int>&array,int low,int high)
{
    if(low < high)
    {
        int mid = (low+high)/2;
        mergeSort(array,low,mid);// sort left half
        mergeSort(array,mid+1,high);// sort right half
        merge(array,low,mid,high);
    }
}

void mergeSort(vector<int>& array)
{
    mergeSort(array,0,array.size()-1);
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    int i =1;
    v.push_back(i);
    v.push_back(i+6);
    v.push_back(i+2);
    v.push_back(i+8);
    v.push_back(i+3);
    v.push_back(i+4);
    v.push_back(i+1);
    v.push_back(i+5);
    v.push_back(i+7);
    vector<int>::iterator it=v.begin();
    while(it!=v.end())
    {
        cout<<" "<<*it;
        it++;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    mergeSort(v);
    it = v.begin();
    while(it!=v.end())
    {
        cout<<" "<<*it;
        it++;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```